# Clickable image over clickable Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to implement a color-picker as clickable magnifier glass over ImageView. 
What is the best way? RelativeLayout with 2 ImageViews? ImageButton on ImageView?

My UI scenario:
Click on the image displays the touched spot as 3x3 pixel matrix in the magnifier.
Click on the magnifier picks the color of the touched pixel. Click on the image changes the zoomed spot to new clicked point and refreshes the matrix in magnifier.

Your help is really appreciated.   ;)

Comment: Thanks for response. My code would not help in this question. Picture would help but I'm new and stackOverflow doesn't let new comers to upload pics. :(

Comment: Please post whatever you have been able to achieve and highlight the part where you're getting stuck. No one is going to implement the entire code for you..